# Master Page's Page_Load method fires twice

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, pageload

Right now I am working on a pretty simple ASP.NET project, and I have run into a problem I can't get my head around: for some reason which is unknown to me, my Master Page's Page_Load method fires twice When i try activating a certain part.
The first time the value of `IsPostBack` is true, the second time it is false. I have searched and found many discussions about this problem but none of the answers helped me solve this.

What can I do in order to solve this and prevent the method from firing twice?

Edit:

Hey, to barak's request here is Catalog.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Catalog.aspx.cs" Inherits="Catalog" Title="Untitled Page" Debug="true" %>
```

****:: קטלוג מוצרים****
  ****מיון המוצרים על פי: חברה, מחיר, דור****

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListPro" runat="server"
    RepeatColumns="3" OnItemCommand="DataListPro_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <div Class="Catalog"> &nbsp;<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkName" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("ProDetails.aspx?id={0}",Eval("idProduct")) %>'
               Text='<%# Bind("NameProduct") %>' CssClass="CatalogLink" Font-Names="00264d" Font-Overline="False" Font-Underline="False" Font-Bold="True"></asp:HyperLink>
           <asp:Label ID="LblIdProduct" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("idProduct") %>' Font-Bold="True" Visible="False"></asp:Label><br />
        <center><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ProductPic") %>' BorderWidth="0px" Height="100px" Width="100px" style="margin: 10px" /><br />
            <strong>
        רק ב</strong><asp:Label ID="LabelPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("price") %>' Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#0099FF"></asp:Label><strong>
        ש"ח!</strong> &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonAddToSal" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" CommandName="AddProduct">הוסף מוצר</asp:LinkButton></center>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" />
</asp:DataList>&nbsp;
<div class="pages">
  <center>
    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonPrevPage" runat="server" CommandName="PrevPage" OnClick="LinkButtonPrevPage_Click">לעמוד הקודם</asp:LinkButton>
      &nbsp;
    אתה נמצא בעמוד:
    <asp:Label
    ID="LabelPageDetails" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      &nbsp;
      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonNextPage"
        runat="server" CommandName="NextPage" OnClick="LinkButtonNextPage_Click">לעמוד הבא</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
  </center>
  <br />
```

Comment: Can you post your page_load code please?

Comment: Only the master page or also the current page fires the OnLoad twice?

Comment: Is the URL the same or different on each load?

Comment: Also try run it on a clean browser with no firebug/ IE dev toolbar or anything see if that helps

Comment: @tanathos, yes, it fires twice only in a certain page. (Catalog.aspx)

Comment: @rangitatanz, the url is the same every time. I did not apply any url rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with asp.net pages being loaded twice in certain browsers. I might be worth retesting with more than one browser (if you are not already doing so).

One cause is an empty src attribute in an image tag i.e.

```
<img src="" alt="" />
```

This [post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t21131-asp-net-page-load-twice-problem.html) gives a more extended discussion - initially pointing at a background attribute in a `td`.

There is an other interesting possiblity in the same post. The use of

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ... AutoEventWireup="true" ... %>
```

with

```
override protected void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

in the same page and presumably also using `Page_Load` could cause the same issue. The solution given is `AutoEventWireup="false"`

**EDIT**

Looking at your code this could be the problem

```
ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ProductPic") %>'
```

If this evaluates at any point to

```
ImageUrl=''
```

The this could cause the `src=""` issue with the images which in turn can cause double postbacks

**EDIT 2**

The only other way are could think of is if you are calling `Response.Redirect` after the page bind (or anywhere). That would cause the page to load twice for sure.

Comment: problem is that when I set AutoEventWireup to false, the Page_Load event doesn't fire at all.

Comment: It won't - it's the use on AutoEventWireup="true" with the OnInit or OnLoad style syntax that causes the issue. You are using Page_Load so you are correct and this can't be the issue

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load() Handles Me.Load
```

I didn't have the page's [AutoEventWireUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) set to anything, so it was defaulting to true. To resolve the issue I explicitly set the AutoEventWireUp property for the page to false.

Answer (score 0):

please send your methods if you want a specific answer.
However here is how your page works, maybe it'll help you understand:
when you load a page - first your actual page is being called ( his `page_load` )
after the page has done rendering - your master page is being called ( his `page_load` ).
any object that sets in `runat=server` and calls a SQL info/ button/ check boxes - which are not set to - `postback=false` - will fire the page again - and with him the `page_load` of the master page.
hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited and added the html code. is the c# code also needed?

Comment: is there any events such as "onDataBound" or any other event that fired automaticly after the page_load?

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me in VS 2013 .net 4.5. At the bottom of the page, I noticed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%# ResolveUrl ("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js") %>'></script>
```

Which renders the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src=''></script>
```

From what I have read, an empty @src will cause this.

I just deleted it as I load jquery as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by setting the autoEventWireUp property to True on the master page and Using 
Sub Page_Load() in the MasterPage CodeBehind, Not Sub Page_Load() Handles Me.Load.

**When I had this**

```
<%@ Master Language="VB"
    CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb"
    Inherits="MasterPage" %>
```

And My Code behind had

```
Sub Page_Load() handles me.load       
    Response.Write("Hello")
End Sub
```

Page would display HelloHello (Code ran twice)

**New Code**

```
<%@ Master Language="VB"
    CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb"
    AutoEventWireup="true"
    Inherits="MasterPage" %>
```

Code Behind

```
Sub Page_Load()
    Response.Write("Hello")
End Sub
```

Page now displays Hello

Answer (score 0):

I have a legacy project that uses WebForms with MasterPages and this one had me scratching my head until a light bulb appeared above my head and I realised the reason, so putting this answer here for anyone who needs it!

My MasterPage Load / init events were being called more than once and I couldn't work out why until I expanded my call stack out to all code (not just mine) and it pointed at the request going through pagetnotfound.aspx

Pagenotfound.aspx on this site uses master pages...

Which may be the reason that fixing empty src attributes fixes this issue - if the browser treats it as a 404 your 404 page will be called and your master page called too.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

any how - your problem is where you have the DATABIND , where the event is being called - it uses "bind" which in his turn - after finished binding - reload the page ( and with it the master page - so you get those page_load twice ).
the best solution for you would be to put all your irelevent functions/declarations within:

```
if (!page.ispostback())
```

now when your master will be loaded - it will skip every part of the code that was already loaded.
notice me if you have further problems.

Comment: Are you sure about that - i don't think databind will literally reload the page - it will just populate a templated control. It's a common error to bind to data twice i.e. in page_load and in a server side event but even that wouldn't postback the page twice - the most common symptom of this would be to lose changes to the grid that you thought were there - such as sorts. Always happy to be proved wrong of course - could you post links if so.

Comment: i am sure about it ( i've came across problem like those in previos projects ) - when you data is binded ( which is a server side event ) the page is being loaded again, you can prevent it in several components - but the deafult is calling a postback event. thanks for the comment any how